Have any western governments asked Ukraine to commit to a specific deadline where the elections would have to be held anyway?
Volodymir Zelensky's presidential mandate has formally expired on May 19, but he remains the president and no new presidential elections were held. This is in accordance with the country's constitute and Ukrainian electoral law, which prohibit holding elections while the country is under martial law (see, e.g., here (in French).)
There are obvious reasons why at the moment this is probably the best for Ukraine, and the majority of Ukrainians would probably back Zelensky anyhow. I wonder however, whether there are any safeguards for preventing the Ukrainian president from becoming a dictator, if the war drags on for a another decade or two? Have any western governments asked Ukraine to commit to a specific deadline where the elections would have to be held anyway?

Related: Can Zelenskyy postpone the next Ukrainian election indefinitely due to war?

Is your question a duplicate of the one @CDJB linked? If not please explain more clearly which aspects you would like to know more about that are not answered there.

@quarague Have any western governments asked Ukraine to commit to a specific deadline where the elections would have to be held anyway?

@againstverylongusernames see the Q. and the comment just above yours.

I am sure that elections held while parts of the country are occupied by a hostile country can't be considered free or fair.

What if you don't get these regions back for a long time? Like, Azerbaijan waited for 20 years to get significant portion of its recognized land back.

[Un]surprisingly, perhaps... WaPo reported last fall:

Despite Russia’s war in Ukraine and a nationwide state of martial law, some Western politicians are pushing the government in Kyiv to hold parliamentary and presidential elections — a prospect that has left many Ukrainian officials scratching their heads.
The proposal — initially floated by Tiny Kox, the Dutch head of the Council of Europe’s Parliamentary Assembly — was also pressed by Sen. Lindsey O. Graham (R-S.C.), during a visit to Kyiv last month with Sens. Richard Blumenthal (D-Conn.) and Elizabeth Warren (D-Mass.), which otherwise focused on solidifying U.S. assistance and bipartisan support for Ukraine.

But these are not official positions from Western governments. I think the answer to that more precise/narrow Q is just 'no' right now. Or at least back in Oct, when NYT wrote:

The Biden administration and European governments supporting Ukraine militarily have not weighed in publicly on an election.

FWTW, some Western analysts/commentators have also taken the opposite position.

The EU has 27 members. No country has joined the EU that has not been a member of the CoE. The Council of Europe's Parliamentary Assembly (PACE) has 46 members, 19 of which aren't members of the EU. Ukraine would like to be a member of the EU so... It is complicated. PACE can't force Ukraine to do anything, but there are concerns with going against PACE recommendations. Tiny Kox was replaced after insisting that Ukraine hold elections soon.

@EllieK: did he? https://www.coe.int/en/web/kyiv/-/pace-president-tiny-kox-it-is-up-to-the-government-parliament-and-the-people-of-ukraine-to-decide-when-and-how-to-conduct-elections

Yes, I'll find the other post. It appeared the day prior to the one you posted which demonstrated to me exactly what you said: neither Tiny Kox nor PACE have much authority over election frequency in Ukraine. I'll find the other URL and post it here.
